# Single query to return rows where field has highest number

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I have the following query:

```
SELECT statement, value, level 
FROM records 
WHERE user_id=10 AND value IS NOT NULL and disabled IS NULL
```

It returns the results like the example below:

```
statement one   | 1   | 3
statement two   | 1   | 3
statement three | 0.5 | 4
statement four  | 0.5 | 4
```

The last value is the value from the level field and I want to select only results for the highest number value. So in this case, the highest number is 4, so I want it to return statement three and four results.

I thought of first querying the highest number and then making another query to include an `AND level=4` syntax.

Just wondering if its possible to do it as a single SQL query.

Comment: Do you want the highest `level` *per `statement`* or the overall highest `level` as condition. And the highest level *before* or *after* applying the other conditions in your query.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `rank()` to find the hightest `level`:

```
SELECT statement, value, level
FROM   (SELECT statement, value, level, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY level DESC) AS rk
        FROM   records 
        WHERE  user_id = 10 AND value IS NOT NULL AND disabled IS NULL)
WHERE  rk = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with max_level as (
    select max(level) as max_level
    from records
)
select statement, "value", level 
from records 
where
    user_id = 10 and
    "value" is not null and
    disabled is null and
    level = (select max_level from max_level)
```

Answer (score 1):

This uses the **`overall` highest value** of `level` as condition.

```
SELECT statement, "value", level 
FROM   records
WHERE  user_id = 10
AND    "value" IS NOT NULL
AND    disabled IS NULL
AND    level = (SELECT max(level) FROM records);
```

This is basically a simplification of [Clodoaldo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22718545/939860). The subquery expression is just fine, since it returns a single value.

Your example actually uses the **highest value of `level` in the result** as condition. [Mureinik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22718569/939860) has an elegant solution for that.

Aside: `value` is a [reserved word in standard SQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html). Better not use the as identifier, even if that's allowed in Postgres.